# Div position in the middle of another vertical element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to align flight duration time just in the middle of each flight path (blue line). But it doesn't work, duration (1:30) is not exactly in the middle of the line and text is not centred. How can I fix that?

[image]

[CodePen code example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbbeLg)

HTML:

```
<span class="col-md-12 roundtrip">
  <div class="col-md-6 trip">Outbound
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="connection">5hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="connection">2hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 trip">Inbound
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>

  </div>
</span>
```

LESS:

```
.roundtrip {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.trip {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 50%;
}
.flight {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.flight-path {
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 85px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
  position: relative;
}
.connection {
  height: 40px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flight-duration {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  width: 81px;
  left: -38px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: add `position: relative;` to `.flight-path` (see https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ for more details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like every time I want to align something vertically I go back to this link:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

I like the way the use cases are organized.

Comment: I glanced at your code again and noticed that if you add position:relative to flight-path then transform/top combination you have works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a table layout. Does this help?

```css
.line {
  width: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.time {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #777;
  height: 10px;
  text-align: center;

}

span {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0px;

}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="time">
    <span>12:34pm</span>
  </div>
</div>
```